# Nested table issue

Tags: html

I have the following nested tables:

```
 <table style="width: 100%; word-wrap: break-word; table-layout: fixed;">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="removeifempty">
                <table style="border-spacing: 0px; border-collapse: collapse; font-family: calibri;
                    font-size: 10pt">
                    <tbody>                            
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word; padding-top: 0px">Result date: </td>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word; padding-top: 0px">March 27, 2013 7:18 PM</td>
                        </tr>                            
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word; padding-top: 0px">Result title:</td>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word; padding-top: 0px">Testing</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word; padding-top: 0px">Performed by:</td>
                            <td style="padding-bottom: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 25px; word-wrap: break-word; padding-top: 0px">Smith, Jonh on March 27, 2013 7:20 PM</td>
                        </tr>                           
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

any ideas of what might be wrong with the above approach?

thanks in advance,
adico

Comment: Tables should be used for tabular data. The obvious problems with this table include accessibility as it is not a well structured table. It does not include table headers <th> or a caption <caption>. You have also specified inline styling which would be better separated out and class names added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

validate it in w3c validation

http://validator.w3.org/

I think that's enough